# Normal Force and Newton's 3rd Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Let's say there are 2 scenarios:

1. A man walks to the wall and then he hit the wall and feels pain.
2. A man pushes the wall and of course, his feet start moving in the opposite direction.
   (No friction)

From these two scenarios, which one caused by Normal Force or Newton's 3rd Law.

Or in another word, what caused the man to feel the pain, and what caused the man to feel his feet moving in the opposite direction?

Comment: Normal Force itself is the consequence of Newton's $3^{rd}$ law.

Comment: This isn’t a “which one” either-or type of scenario. Both apply to both scenarios.

Comment: Normal force is the equal and opposite force(N3 pair) to his push. Both scenarios are same except in number 1 there is friction that stops number 2 happening. If there is no friction number 2 will definitely happen even if very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Both. Hitting and pushing are both actions that happen at slightly different time scales. As a result, the normal force from the wall = equals and opposite of the action.

Answer (score 1):

The Normal Force is an example of the 'Reaction force' that comes up in Newton's third law. In both your scenarios, if we consider the force applied by the man on the wall as the action force, the wall exerts an equal and opposite force on the man - this is the Normal Reaction Force.

In case it's difficult to understand how the normal force is a reaction force, try to come up with an example of a scenario where you have a normal force acting on a body, but no other forces exist. That shouldn't be possible.

As is mentioned in another answer, the reason the man feels pain depends on the time scales over which the forces are applied.

Comment: *"'Reaction force' that comes up in Newton's second law."*: I suppose you meant "Newton's third law".

Answer (score -1):

The brain's perception of force is a delayed response. The brain receives information through nerves located just underneath the skin. Hence, there may be a perception that Newton's third law is violated because of a delay in the signal reaching the brain via the nerves.